# Shiny App Question: Error in match.arg(position) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Tags: r, shiny

New to shiny and trying to create a dashboard with a histogram of sepal width for each species. How do I accomplish that? any help would be appreciated.

Each radio button for each species: Setosa, Versicolor, Virginica and I want to plot histogram based on these choices.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

data("iris")


ui <- fluidPage(
  

  titlePanel("Iris Data Visualization!"),

  sidebarLayout(
  
    sidebarPanel(
      
    
      sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                  label = "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
      
    ),
    
    radioButtons("spec", "Species:",
                 c("Setosa" = "Set",
                   "Versicolor" = "Ver",
                   "Virginica" = "Vir"
                   )),
   
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
      
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  
  dist <- switch(input$spec,
                 "Set" ="setosa",
                 "Ver" = "versicolor",
                 "Vir" ="virginica"
  )
  df <- reactive({
    iris%>%filter(Species==dist)
  })
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    
     y<-df$Sepal.Length
     bins <- seq(min(y), max(y), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(y, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
         xlab = "Sepal Length",
         main = "Histogram of Sepal Length")
    
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Where do you want the `radioButtons`? You have them both outside the `sidebarPanel()` and the `mainPanel()` which is confusing the `sidebarLayout()` function. Take note of how the parenthesis are grouping your inputs.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. quick question. I took the reactive off the data subsetting part this time since it's under the render() function . Does it make sense? Please see the following. Do I need the reactive to be there?